# What is the operator norm of $Tf(x) = x^2f(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $H = L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and $T : H \to H,\, Tf(x) = x^2f(x) $.

$T$ is linear.

$$\|Tf\|_{L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})} = \sqrt{\int_0^1x^4f^2(x)dx} \leq\sqrt{\int_0^1f^2(x)dx} = \|f\|_{L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})} $$

$T$ is linear and bounded therefore it's continuous. Also
$\|T|| \leq 1$.

I tried finding solution to $\|Tf\|_{L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})}  = \|f\|_{L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})} $

I found $$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2x-1}{x^4-1}}$$

but it's not in $L^2$ so it doesn't work.

anyone knows an $f$ to reach $1$, I'm not even sure it's $1$.

any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Hint: take $f=1_{[a,1]}$ where $a < 1$ is a positive real number close to $1$.

Comment: The answers below are fine, but one may add, that the approach by the OP can't work since there is no $L^2$ function for which the norm is attained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Then $$\|f_n\|_2=\sqrt{\frac1{2n+1}}$$
and
$$\|Tf_n\|_2=\sqrt{\frac1{2n+5}}$$
Since 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\|Tf_n\|_2}{\|f_n\|_2}=1$$
we have that $\|T\|\ge1$.

Comment: I understand your solution. But why do you know the sequence $x^n$ will work?

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication by $x^2$ on $[0,1]$.  $T$ is a self-adjoint operator.  The essential range of the multiplier $x^2$ is $[0,1]$, so the spectrum of $T$ is $[0,1]$.  The spectral radius of $T$ is $1$, and (since $T$ is self-adjoint), the norm of $T$ is $1$.

Comment: As Dirk notes, there is no $f$ where the norm is attained.  Here, we can see: $1$ is in the spectrum of $T$, but is not an eigenvalue of $T$.